# Cómo implementar un demo como el siguiente en Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

He implementado este pequeño demo usando la biblioteca de Google "Blockly", el objetivo es implementar este mismo demo en Angular, sin embargo, revisando la documentación oficial me di cuenta que hay poca información al respecto sobre como hacerlo, también revisé los ejemplos que brindan en la documentación en los cuales viene un ejemplo en Angular, pero este ejemplo lo único que hace es incluir la biblioteca en el proyecto.

Cabe mencionar que tengo poca experiencia utilizando Angular, por lo cual agradecería si me pueden apoyar con un enlace o demo que me permita alcanzar mi objetivo.

[Ejemplos del uso de blockly](https://github.com/google/blockly-samples/tree/master/examples)

[Documentación de blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/overview)

```js
//Custom block

Blockly.Blocks['login'] = {
  init: function () {
    this.appendDummyInput()
      .appendField('Login')
      .setAlign(Blockly.ALIGN_CENTRE);
    this.appendDummyInput()
      .appendField('user')
      .appendField(new Blockly.FieldTextInput(''), 'user');
    this.appendDummyInput()
      .appendField('password')
      .appendField(new Blockly.FieldTextInput(''), 'pass');
    this.appendDummyInput()
      .appendField('url')
      .appendField(new Blockly.FieldTextInput(''), 'url');
    this.setInputsInline(false);
    this.setNextStatement(true, null);
    this.setPreviousStatement(true, null);
    this.setColour(230);
    this.setTooltip('Login into the obtained page');
    this.setHelpUrl('');
  },
};

Blockly.JavaScript['login'] = function (block) {
  let user = block.getFieldValue('user');
  let pass = block.getFieldValue('pass');
  let url = block.getFieldValue('url');

  let code;

  if (user.length == 0 || /^\s+$/.test(user) || 
      pass.length == 0 || /^\s+$/.test(pass) ||
      url.length == 0 || /^\s+$/.test(url)) {

    code = 'window.alert("All fields are required!!!");\n';

  } else {
    code = `window.alert("` + user + ` ` + pass + ` ` + url + `");
window.open("`+url+`","_blank");\n`


  }

  return code;
};




//--------------------------------------------------

let workspacePlayground = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv', {
  toolbox: document.getElementById('toolbox'),
  zoom:
  {
    controls: true,
    wheel: true,
    startScale: 1.0,
    maxScale: 2,
    minScale: 0.5,
    scaleSpeed: 1.2
  }
});

function UpdateFunction(event) {

  let code = Blockly.JavaScript.workspaceToCode(workspacePlayground);
  document.getElementById('code').innerHTML = code

}

workspacePlayground.addChangeListener(UpdateFunction);

// save blocks
function saveWorkspace() {

  let xml = Blockly.Xml.workspaceToDom(Blockly.mainWorkspace);
  let domToPretty = Blockly.Xml.domToPrettyText(xml);
  window.localStorage.setItem("myProgram", domToPretty);

}

// restore blocks
function restoreWorkspace() {

  let program = window.localStorage.getItem("myProgram");
  Blockly.mainWorkspace.clear();

  let textToDom = Blockly.Xml.textToDom(program);
  Blockly.Xml.domToWorkspace(Blockly.mainWorkspace, textToDom);

}

// delete blocks
function deleteWorkspace() {

  window.localStorage.clear();

}

// execute code
function execute() {
  Blockly.JavaScript.addReservedWords('code');
  let code = Blockly.JavaScript.workspaceToCode(workspacePlayground);
  try {
    eval(code);
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }

}
```

```css
.blockly-container {
  
  height: 60vh; 
  width: 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/google-blockly@1.0.0/blockly_compressed.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/google-blockly@1.0.0/javascript_compressed.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/google-blockly@1.0.0/blocks_compressed.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/google-blockly@1.0.0/msg/js/en.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="container py-5">

        <h1 class="text-center">Blockly Test</h1>
    
        <div class="row my-3">
          <div class="col">
            <div id="blocklyDiv" class="blockly-container"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="row my-3">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2>Output</h2>
            <pre id="code"></pre>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="saveWorkspace();">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="restoreWorkspace();">Restore</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteWorkspace();">Delete</button>
            <button id="runButton" type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="execute();">Execute</button>

          </div>
        </div>
    
      </div>

    <xml id="toolbox" style="display: none">
        <category name="Variables" custom="VARIABLE" colour="330"></category>
        <category name="Functions" custom="PROCEDURE" colour="330"></category>
        <category name="Logic" colour="210">
            <block type="controls_if"></block>
            <block type="logic_compare"></block>
            <block type="logic_operation"></block>
            <block type="logic_boolean"></block>
        </category>
        <category name="Loops" colour="120">
            <block type="controls_whileUntil"></block>
            <block type="controls_repeat_ext"></block>
            <block type="controls_for"></block>
        </category>
        <category name="Math" colour="230">
            <block type="math_number"></block>
            <block type="math_arithmetic"></block>
        </category>
        <category name="Functions" colour="290" custom="PROCEDURE"></category>
        <category name="Text" colour="150">
            <block type="text"></block>
            <block type="text_print"></block>
        </category>
        <category name="Login" colour="300">
            <block type="login"></block>
        </category>
    </xml>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: En su sitio vienen ejemplos con varias tecnologias incluida angular: https://github.com/google/blockly-samples/tree/master/examples/blockly-angular